# Left join with "select"

Tags: mysql

Good day,

Could someone please kindly explain to me what the below syntax is doing? I understand everything before it which is to join a table with this but in this case it's not a table that it's joining to, it looks like a selection and I was really confused about what it's trying to select.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PARTRACKINFO.INVLOGID AS INVLOGID, GROUP_CONCAT(PARTRACKINFO.TRACKVALUE) AS TRACKVALUE
    FROM (SELECT TIINVENTORYLOG.INVENTORYLOGID AS INVLOGID, CONCAT(PARTTRACKING.ABBR, ': ',
            GROUP_CONCAT((CASE

                WHEN PARTTRACKING.TYPEID = 20 THEN SUBSTRING(TIINVENTORYLOG.INFODATE FROM 1 FOR 11)
                WHEN PARTTRACKING.TYPEID = 30 THEN SUBSTRING(TIINVENTORYLOG.INFODATE FROM 1 FOR 11)
                WHEN PARTTRACKING.TYPEID = 40 THEN TIINVENTORYLOGSN.SERIALNUM
                WHEN PARTTRACKING.TYPEID = 50 THEN CAST(TIINVENTORYLOG.INFODOUBLE AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                WHEN PARTTRACKING.TYPEID = 60 THEN CAST(TIINVENTORYLOG.INFODOUBLE AS DECIMAL(18,5))
                WHEN PARTTRACKING.TYPEID = 70 THEN TIINVENTORYLOG.INFOINTEGER
                WHEN PARTTRACKING.TYPEID = 80 THEN TIINVENTORYLOG.INFOINTEGER
                ELSE TIINVENTORYLOG.INFO
            END ))) AS TRACKVALUE
        FROM TIINVENTORYLOG
            INNER JOIN PARTTRACKING ON (TIINVENTORYLOG.PARTTRACKINGID = PARTTRACKING.ID)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TIINVENTORYLOGSN ON (TIINVENTORYLOG.ID = TIINVENTORYLOGSN.TIINVENTORYLOGID)
            GROUP BY TIINVENTORYLOG.INVENTORYLOGID, PARTTRACKING.ABBR, PARTTRACKING.SORTORDER
        ORDER BY PARTTRACKING.SORTORDER) AS PARTRACKINFO
    GROUP BY PARTRACKINFO.INVLOGID) TRACKINFO ON (INVENTORYLOG.ID = TRACKINFO.INVLOGID)
```

Thanks

Comment: Where's it from? Who wrote it? Why not ask them?

Comment: Alternatively, does [the documentation on subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) answer your question?

Comment: You can join with a subquery, it's like creating a table that contains the result of the query, and joining with that.

Comment: You can run each subquery on its own an look what it returns. Start small, work your way up to the larger query.